# How can I automatically duplicate a site's pages onto network site?

Tags: multisite, automation

Basically there are sub-sites that inherit all the pages. But I have worked out ways for each page to be unique to their location, by creating a shortcode that pulls in the Blog Description. The point is I am not trying to spam the web, but this site needs to reach different people in different towns. And I don't want to repeat all the content each time.

I have installed threewp broadcast and multipost MU and tested them out, but when you add a site you have to go through each time you add each page to the new site. There are 50+ pages. Essentially I want to make sure the main site is right, then add a new site and have all the pages automatically added.

I can go through and mess with the settings on each site to give it the right homepage and all that but adding the pages individually is a pain... ideas?

Comment: check out wpmudev.org 's new blog template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is possible with the plugin WordPress MU Sitewide Tags:  (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-sitewide-tags/)

With that plugin you can republish content from all sites OR a selection and you can choose to publish it to the main site OR to a new subsite.

Comment: Piet, I have looked through the info on the plugin and it feels pretty sparse, and direction you can give me on setting this plugin up right.  I have a main blog, and I want it to push out to a new site.  So I know I need to create a new site, and then go back to the plugin and populate to the newly created site.  also will this plugin update the posts/pages across the "sub-sites" if you update one on the master site?

Comment: I agree that the documentation for that plugin is not great (and the same goes for the choice of name of the plugin actually). But if you look around a bit on the WP forums (http://wordpress.org/tags/wordpress-mu-sitewide-tags?forum_id=10) or on the dev-site (http://wpmututorials.com/plugins/using-the-sitewide-tags-plugin/), you will find that you do not need to make a new blog: the plugin does that for you. And you can republish all or some of it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it's something along the lines of:

Export the database, find the posts you want and delete everything else in the exported file, search and replace so that the posts belong to the subsite you want, then import the new SQL back into the database.

It could also be that sites have a list of which post ID belong to them... you have to look at the database content.

... WHatever you find the simple replacement to be, you'll be copying over 50 posts at a time (or however many you have).

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of new searches: ThreeWP Broadcast is now capable of broadcasting several posts at a time using the plugins "Send To Many" and "Queue".

See [Broadcast's page on Wordpress.org](http://wordpress.org/plugins/threewp-broadcast/).

Comment: Are you in any way associated with this plugin? You are a new member as of today and have already posted two answers that do not much more than recommend the same plugins. That seems odd, and makes me think "advertising" much more than it does "helpful answer to the question".

Comment: I am the author of the plugin.

Comment: You can promote your own projects here but you are expected to clearly identify yourself as affiliated with the recommendation, and you are still expected to follow the basic rules for quality answers, such as not posting essentially link-only answers such as this one.